# Flutter build ipa without buildName and BuildNumber

Tags: ios, flutter

I have set the version in my pubspec.yaml file like below,

```
version: 3.0.0+5
```

and put these key/string in my Info.plist file under my project.

```
<key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
<string>$(FLUTTER_BUILD_NAME)</string>

<key>CFBundleVersion</key>
<string>$(FLUTTER_BUILD_NUMBER)</string>
```

I have open XCode and check the target under my project, and in the General tab, the Version and Build column seems normal, the numbers are correct.

And then when I run `flutter build ipa` in my terminal, it just build an archive without Version.

After the fail, I change the Version and Build number directly in Xcode, which cause the change in Info.plist below.

```
<key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
<string>$(MARKETING_VERSION)</string>

<key>CFBundleVersion</key>
<string>$(CURRENT_PROJECT_VERSION)</string>
```

And I run `flutter build ipa` again, this time it works fine.

Is this behavior normal that I have to change the Version and Build manually?

Or is there something wrong with my setting somewhere in my project?

---

I've tried method below

1. flutter clean
2. clean build in xcode
3. delete derivedata folder in xcode
4. flutter pub get
5. cd ios
6. pod install
7. pod update
8. flutter build ipa

Still not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those who counter this problem, here's my solution.

Open `Runner.xcworkspace` => PROJECT => Info => Configurations => Release => Runner => add `Generated.xcconfig` .

Comment: How do you add Generated.xcconfig inside Configurations?

Answer (score 0):

Try below steps:

1. `flutter clean`
2. `flutter pub get`
3. `cd ios`
4. `pod install`
5. `pod update`
6. `flutter build ipa`

Comment: I've tried, didn't work.

Comment: have you cleared Derievedata ?

Comment: what is derivedata?

Comment: thats cached data when generate builds from xcode

Comment: how do I do it besides ````flutter clean```` and ````pod clean````?

Comment: you can do it from xcode : open xcode  -> preferences  location -> derived data -> move to bin and clear bin as well.

Comment: still not working

Answer (score 0):

On my system have to do this first:
flutter build ios

On my system, this is the only way a flutter build number specified in the .yaml will be passed on correctly to xcode build system.

I usually wait until the code build phase and then CTRL-C and then flutter build ipa.

EDIT: Readup a bit - flutter build ios prepare the code system , according to https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/64626

Use --config-only if you want that part to go faster ...